# React create new component instantly

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am wondering if there is any good way to create a React component instantly (not having to wait for the setState to execute a re-render), or any other ideas that could solve the following problem:

Say I am rendering a list of **Text** components that are all *contenteditable* `<p/>`'s that the user can type in. When the user presses `Enter`, a new **Text** is created under the current one, and the caret then moves to this new component, allowing the user to type.

I have implemented this and it is working, but adding a new **Text** to the rendered list with `setState()` is too slow, and if the user presses `Enter` and begins typing immediately, some text is added to the wrong node or lost because the re-render does not happen quick enough.

I need the user to be able to press `Enter` and type immediately without losing any text, and the user should also be able to press `Enter` many times in quick succession to create multiple new **Text** components, which also does not work for the same reason.

The solution should not only not lose any of the typed keys, but also display to the user the typed text (and newly created **Text** components) as quickly as possible.

Here is an extremely contrived example. Go to the end of one of the texts, press `Enter` and quickly type. You will see that some of the text gets added to the first component instead of the second.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-xbr9pf

Example output showing the order in which keys were pressed:

[image: example]

Thank you!

Comment: Can you post your solution so I can take a look at why it's slow?

Comment: React isn't inherently slow (quite the opposite), although it is quite easy to slow things down when dealing with lists if you aren't paying very close attention to what is being rendered and why.

Comment: I added an example @technophyle

Comment: Pro tip: React has `Ref` to deal with native DOM, don't need to use document API to access the DOM elements.

Comment: Your example is working fine for me, but one major issue is that you're not using keys correctly. Every time you add a new text the entire list is re-rendered. Keys should be stable across renders. More info: https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318

Comment: Okay, I'll check it out @AlexeyLebedev. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any specific need to use `p` tag with `contentEditable` true, instead of an `input`?

Comment: I'm just doing a lot of complex text manipulations, syntax highlighting, etc.. These things seem to be much easier with a contentEditable, which gives the developer much more control

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few problems with your implementation, including `that = this`, constantly getting elements by `id`s instead of by react refs, hacks with `textContent = textContent`, trying to `focus` before setState has kicked in and so on

I've done some minimal edits to your example like changing `keyup` to `keydown`, using `preventDefault` and `ref`s instead of finding element by id. It now works as expected

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-11g7ec

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do something like this:

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Texts} from './Texts';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    texts: [
      {id: 0, content: 'Hey ! I\'m first textbox'}
    ]
  }

  updateTexts = (id,newContent) => {
    const updatedText = [...this.state.texts]
    updatedText[id].content = newContent
    this.setState({
      texts: updatedText
    })
  }

  handleKeyDown = (e,id) => {
    if(e.key === 'Enter'){
      const newTextBox = [...this.state.texts]
      newTextBox.push({id: id+1, content: ''})
      this.setState({texts: newTextBox})
    }
  }

  render(){

    return(
        <Texts 
          data={this.state.texts} 
          updateFxn = {this.updateTexts} 
          handleKeyDown= {this.handleKeyDown} 
        />
    ) 
  }
}

export default App;
```

**Texts.js**

```
import React from 'react';

export const Texts = ({data,updateFxn, handleKeyDown}) => {
    return(
        <React.Fragment>
            {
                data.map ((item,i) => (
                        <input 
                            key={i} 
                            type="text" 
                            value={item.content} 
                            onChange={(e)=>updateFxn(item.id,e.target.value)} 
                            onKeyDown={(e)=> handleKeyDown(e,item.id)} 
                        />
                    )
                )
            }

        </React.Fragment>
        )
}
```

You can just add a basic logic for adding focus to the new element we have created/ simply to the last element of this state array. Rest everything should work just fine.

> Also, you can just create another field in updateTexts functions (like a type) and then you can use that type to either add new elements (like we are doing right now) or to even remove the items from the array too.

Something like :

```
updateTexts = (id,type,newContent) => {
    if(type===1){
      const updatedText = [...this.state.texts]
      updatedText[id].content = newContent
      this.setState({
        texts: updatedText
      })
    }else if(type==0){
      //Logic to remove the element
    }

  }
```